# Issues with Calculator Program - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

...I'm new to Python & working through fundamentals; currently I'm working through this Calculator Program in Python but I'm  having issues with the following items:
1. I want to print the users answers to all of the users inputs when they identify that they no longer want to perform any more calculations..I created the "calc_store" as an empty list but it hasn't worked yet.
2. I want to "end" or terminate the program if the user is unable to enter one of the identified math operations after 3 attempts. I keep getting error statements about an "Indentation Error" at line 71 but I can't figure out why.
3. Am I using an appropriate method for saving the users input into lists?

Answers are great but explanations are important so I can learn! Code is below:

```
def Calculations():  
    Calc_store=[]
    answer_count = 0
    incorrect_count = 0

    acknow = input("Please choose from the following math operations: +,-,*,//, **:  ")
    num1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: "))

    if acknow == '**':

        pow1 = int(input("Please enter your first number*: "))
        pow2 = int(input("To what power?"))

        print('{} ** {} = '.format(pow1, pow2))
        print(pow1 ** pow2)
        Power_1= pow2 ** pow2
        Calc_store.append(Power_1)
        answer_count +=1
        Repeat_Calculations()          


    elif acknow == '+':
        num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
        print('{} + {} = '.format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 + num2)
        Addition_1= num1 + num2
        Calc_store.append(Addition_1)
        answer_count +=1
        Repeat_Calculations()

    elif acknow == '-':
        num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
        print('{} - {} = '.format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 - num2)
        Subtract_1= num1 - num2
        Calc_store.append(Subtract_1)
        answer_count +=1
        Repeat_Calculations()

    elif acknow == '*':
        num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
        print('{} * {} = '.format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 * num2)
        Multiply_1= num1 * num2
        Calc_store.append(Multiply_1)
        answer_count +=1
        Repeat_Calculations()

    elif acknow == '/':
        num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
        print('{} / {} = '.format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 / num2)
        Divide_1= num1 / num2
        Calc_store.append(Divide_1)
        answer_count +=1
        Repeat_Calculations()


    else:
        print("Sorry I don't recognize that, try another operatror")
        incorrect_count +=1

    if incorrect_count > 2:
        print("Too many incorrect answers")


    Repeat_Calculations()

def Repeat_Calculations():

    calculate2 = input("Do you want to calculate again? Please type Y for YES or N for NO: ")

    if calculate2.upper() == 'Y':
        Calculations()
    elif calculate2.upper() == 'N':
        # This was the piece that I couldn't get to work...can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
        print('Bonsoir Elliot! The result of your %s calculculations were: [%s]' %(answer_count, Calc_store))
    else:
        Repeat_Calculations()



Calculations()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
incorrect_count = 0
answer_count = 0
Calc_store=[]
def Calculations():  
    global incorrect_count
    global answer_count
    global Calc_store
    operations = ['+','-','*','//', '**']
    acknow = input("Please choose from the following math operations: +,-,*,//, **:  ")

    if acknow == '**':

        pow1 = int(input("Please enter your first number*: "))
        pow2 = int(input("To what power?"))

        print('{} ** {} = '.format(pow1, pow2))
        print(pow1 ** pow2)
        Power_1= pow2 ** pow2

        Calc_store.append(str(pow1)+' ** '+str(pow2)+" = "+str(Power_1))
        answer_count +=1
        Repeat_Calculations()          


    elif acknow == '+':
        num1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
        print('{} + {} = '.format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 + num2)
        Addition_1= num1 + num2
        Calc_store.append(str(num1)+' + '+str(num2)+" = "+str(Addition_1))
        answer_count +=1
        Repeat_Calculations()

    elif acknow == '-':
        num1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
        print('{} - {} = '.format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 - num2)
        Subtract_1= num1 - num2
        Calc_store.append(str(num1)+' - '+str(num2)+" = "+str(Subtract_1))
        answer_count +=1
        Repeat_Calculations()

    elif acknow == '*':
        num1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
        print('{} * {} = '.format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 * num2)
        Multiply_1= num1 * num2
        Calc_store.append(str(num1)+' * '+str(num2)+" = "+str(Multiply_1))
        answer_count +=1
        Repeat_Calculations()

    elif acknow == '//':
        num1 = int(input("Please enter your first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Please enter your second number: "))
        print('{} // {} = '.format(num1, num2))
        print(num1 // num2)
        Divide_1=num1 // num2
        Calc_store.append(str(num1)+' // '+str(num2)+" = "+str(Divide_1))
        Calc_store.append(Divide_1)
        answer_count +=1
        Repeat_Calculations()


    else:
        print("Sorry I don't recognize that, try another operatror")
        incorrect_count +=1
        if incorrect_count > 2:
            print("Too many incorrect answers")
            return -1
        Calculations()




    Repeat_Calculations()

def Repeat_Calculations():

    calculate2 = input("Do you want to calculate again? Please type Y for YES or N for NO: ")

    if calculate2.upper() == 'Y':
        Calculations()
    elif calculate2.upper() == 'N':
        # This was the piece that I couldn't get to work...can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
        print('Bonsoir Elliot! The result of your %s calculculations were:' %(answer_count))
        for cal in Calc_store:
            print(cal)
    else:
        Repeat_Calculations()


Calculations()
```

So here is the code. Changes I made from your code:
1. Since you're using

```
incorrect_count = 0
answer_count = 0
Calc_store=[]
```

in both functions, you need them to be global or you return them. I chose making them gloabl.

2. Saving calculations in the form of list. And this list has operation converted to string, because you just need to show them.
3. Ending on 3 incorrect options, I guess you already did that but a few changes I made to make that work.

More on explanation please ask in comments.

Comment: The use of making the functions "global" was the part I had struggled with but didn't implement correctly so I gave up on it but this makes complete sense. I over thought the printing of the list....thanks for the help & for the explanation on the improvements...I appreciate the insight / help!